# How to show HTML DOM object in html using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

**Dom object have that i parse from html string using DOMParser and edit this html**

```
domObj= '
<html> 
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>'
```

**In component.html **

```
<div [innerHTML]="domObj"></div>
```

**I am getting result in browser**
[object HTMLDocument]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser%60)

```
const domObj= '<html> \
<head> 
<style> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p>this is a paragraph</p> 
</body> 
</html>';
```

Get the document object

```
let doc = parser.parseFromString(domObj, "application/xml")
```

Construct the XML string

```
let xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc.documentElement);
```

Select and set innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('titlebar').innerHTML = xml;
```

Comment: FYI `document.getElementById('titlebar').innerHTML ` is not supposed to be used in angular, since it has other ways to bind data

Comment: My mistake, I overlooked the tags in the question. I didn't realize this was pertaining to Angular.

Comment: thanks @laujonat this solution is worked for me but one problem is there it taking all as string i mean it not taking style as style elements . body elements not taking class from style tag

Answer (score 1):

What you tried to do was correct, but you have to use tild (`) instead of single quotes ('). Check the stackblitz implementation [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17rf6j)

You can refer here for template literals [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Solution -1. Using single quotes ( ' )**

```
domObj=
    '<html>'+ 
    '<head>'+
    '<style>'+
    '</style>'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body>'+
    '<p>this is a paragraph</p>'+
    '</body>'+
    '</html>'
}
```

**Solution - 2. Using tild ( ` )**

```
domObj=`
    <html> 
    <head>
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    </body>
    </html>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the single backtick :

```
domObj= `<html> 
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>`
```

ex.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkv6bw?file=src/app/app.component.ts